# How do I check if emacs has a library installed?

Tags: emacs

I want to check whether pymacs has been installed.

Comment: why do you want to know?  what's the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

- type apropos, then pymacs. If it finds the symbols, it was loaded.
- (require 'pymacs) -- if it does not return error, it was loaded
- if you already loaded it, it called (provide 'pymacs), and the variable load-history keeps the symbols

There are still other ways to ckeck it.

Comment: You can also call require like `(require 'pymacs nil 'noerror)`.  Then it returns false if the library can't be loaded instead of erroring.  Returns non-nil if the library was already loaded or loaded successfully.

Comment: `(require 'pymacs)` errs if the library loaded ok but failed to `(provide 'pymacs)` while loading.

Answer (score 6):

`M-x locate-library` will tell you if emacs can find the library in its `load-path`. If it does not return anything you might need to edit your `load-path` first.

Comment: `(locate-library "pymacs")` returns the absolute file name of the library without actually loading it, or nil if not found, regardless of whether or not it has been loaded yet in this session.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're talking about ELPA packages, but I have the following definitions in my .emacs:

```
  (defun sh-elpa-ensure-package (name)
      "Make sure that a particular package is installed; if not then
  automatically download, compile and install it.

  This is primarily used by sh-elpa-require to allow deployment of
  the configuration to a new machine - packages will therefore be
  downloaded on that fresh machine (following installation they are
  automatically kept up to date by the package manager).

  Use this as follows:
  (sh-elpa-ensure-package 'org)"
      (if (not (package-installed-p name))
          (package-install name)))

    (defun sh-elpa-require (name)
      "A replacement for the standard Emacs 'require'
  function. This uses sh-elpa-require to download and install a
  package if necessary prior to using the standard 'require'
  function to import it. This is useful to allow the configuration
  to just 'sh-elpa-require' a package and not have to bother
  checking whether it has been installed yet."
      (sh-elpa-ensure-package name)
      (require name))
```

I can then include code such as the following in my .emacs to activate the package - if it's not already installed then this will download it from ELPA and byte-compile it before it is "required":

```
(sh-elpa-require 'pymacs)
```

If you're just talking about checking whether a package is installed from elisp, then you can also pick the bones of that out of the above snippet - see the `(if (not (package-installed-p name))` bit.

Comment: First make sure `(package-initialize)` has been called. Otherwise  `(package-installed-p name)` returns `nil` for packages installed in ~/.emacs.d/elpa/, which is quite buffling, as trying `(package-install name)` then complains the file already exists.